# Rails Highcharts Heatmap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm looking at implementing a high charts heat map in my rails application, I have tried using script and gems PerfectlyNormal and Lazy Highcharts but just can't get anything working. I was wondering if anyone has had some success with heat maps and rails and might have any information to help guide me. I have been using the documentation [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap) as reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Lazy Highcharts [wiki](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts/wiki), included are files:

```
vendor/assets/javascripts/highcharts/highcharts.js
vendor/assets/javascripts/highcharts/highcharts-more.js
vendor/assets/javascripts/highcharts/modules/exporting.js
vendor/assets/javascripts/highcharts/adapters/mootools-adapter.js
vendor/assets/javascripts/highcharts/adapters/prototype-adapter.js
```

Meanwhile, to get heatmap, you required this file:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
```

So I guess that Lazy Highcharts doesn't support heatmap.